# Xcode 4.2 how to automatically compile source files dragged into project?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

A quick question,

Up to date, all of my Xcode 4.2 projects automatically compiled everything that I dragged into the list of sources on the left. But recently this stopped happening. The files that I drag into the project just sit there, and I have to manually add them to the project>build phases > compile sources.

How can I restore the Xcode's ability to automatically compile everything that I drag and copy into the project?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any window when you drag and drop the files?

Comment: Just guessing: last time you added files to some project you unchecked that chekbox next to "Add to target". XCode rememberd that and is now not adding files to target automatically?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem: the Xcode was adding files to the Unit tests target, not the main project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whe you drag files into the Project Navigator, you get a confirmation window where you can select the targets to which to add the files. Make sure the check box is checked.

[image]